# Python Dash navigation and dashboard from bootstrap template not working

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

Since there are hardly any templates available yet for Python Dash, I'm construction my own template for dashboarding/navigation, using resources available like bootstrap and standard jquery.

I converted [this template](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) to Python Dash, but for some reason, both toggling and some css do not work as in the live [demo](https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html#). I assume I'm doing something wrong with the `data-*` and `arial-*` parameters, but for completeness, I supplied all code, except the `css`, which can be found in the demo source code. What is the reason my template does not work as expected like the live demo? Especially, why does toggling not work and why is markup different?

`app.py:`

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = [
    {
        'href': 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'rel': 'stylesheet',
        'integrity': 'sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]

external_scripts = [
    {
        'src': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]


app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_scripts=external_scripts,
    external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    className='wrapper',
    children=[
        # <!-- Sidebar -->
        html.Nav(
            id='sidebar',
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=html.H3('DGTL'),
                    className='sidebar-header'
                ),
                html.Ul(
                    className='list-unstyled components',
                    children=[
                        html.P('Navigation'),
                        html.Li(
                            className='active',
                            children=[
                                html.A(
                                    'Home',
                                    href='#homeSubmenu',
                                    className = 'dropdown-toggle',
                                    **{'aria-expanded': 'false', 'data-toggle': 'collapse'}
                                ),
                                html.Ul(
                                    className='collapse list-unstyled',
                                    id='homeSubmenu',
                                    children=[
                                        html.Li(
                                            html.A(
                                                'Home 1',
                                                href='#'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        html.Li(
                                            html.A(
                                                'Home 2',
                                                href='#'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        html.Li(
                                            html.A(
                                                'Home 3',
                                                href='#'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                )
                            ]
                        ),
                        html.Li(
                            children=[
                                html.A(
                                    'About',
                                    href='#'
                                )
                            ]
                        ),
                        html.Li(
                            children=[
                                html.A(
                                    'Contact',
                                    href='#'
                                )
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]

        ),

         # <!-- Page Content -->
         html.Div(
             id='content',
             children=[
                 html.Nav(
                     className = 'navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light',
                     children=[
                         html.Div(
                             className = 'container-fluid',
                             children = [
                                 html.Button(
                                     type = 'button',
                                     id = 'sidebarCollapse',
                                     className = 'btn btn-info',
                                     children = [
                                         html.I(className='fas fa-align-left'),
                                         html.Span('Toggle Sidebar')
                                     ]
                                 )
                             ]
                         )
                     ]
                 )
             ]
         ),
        html.Script(
            '''
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                });
            });
            '''
        )
    ]
)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: the field of data-* is still not fully supported I think in dash and it is still under active development. Here is the issue for implementing this task: https://community.plot.ly/t/can-data-attributes-be-created-in-dash/7222

Comment: Does this goes the behavior like not toggling, and wrongly coulored tabs in the navbar?

Comment: yes to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Hi @Dendrobates, Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your sidebar is not toggling is because the `html.Script` is not loaded on page load but on a later point when dash is rendering the page.

If you are using chrome right click on your page and view the source code (do not use the developer console) then you can see what is loaded on page load.

You need to add your javascript as a file so it is included in the initial page.
See [Adding Your Own CSS and JavaScript to Dash Apps](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources) for details.

Comment: Hi @phifre you are right. I have tried your solution and it works. However, when I restarted my app it does not work anymore. What could be happening that sometimes it works and load properly and sometimes it does not?

When I go to Developer tools, Networks, JS I see "Request Headers: Provisional headers are shown". Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@phifre has given a partially right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302839/2224168) so I wanted to give one which addresses all the questions and comments for the sake of completeness.

The `data-*` and `aria-*` attributes have nothing to do with the toggling of the sidebar. The `data-*` attribute is for collapsing the Home submenu in the mentioned [demo](https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html).

Besides, for [@JustInTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257649/python-dash-navigation-and-dashboard-from-bootstrap-template-not-working#comment91463208_52257649)'s info, the issue of `data-*` and `aria-*` attributes was already [fixed](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/237) by the time this question was asked.

I tried the answer given by @phifre but it was also not successful probably for the same reason. The javascript was not able to find the `#sidebarCollapse` element which is rendered by dash at a later point in time.

"Wrongly coloured tabs in the navbar" could be a css issue.

**Solution**

Since the sidebar and button is static and do not affect any dash components, I suggest that they be inserted through `index_string`. See [Customizing Dash's HTML Index Template](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources). Working `app.py` below.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = [
    {
        'href': 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'rel': 'stylesheet',
        'integrity': 'sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]

external_scripts = [
    {
        'src': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    },
    {
        'src': 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'integrity': 'sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]


app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_scripts=external_scripts,
    external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.index_string = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>DGTL</h3>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <p>Navigation</p>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                            <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            {%app_entry%}
            <footer>
                {%config%}
                {%scripts%}
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>'''
app.layout = html.Div()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```